# Proper process for sending Swift events to Javascript in React Native

Tags: javascript, swift, react-native

I've been attempting to build comprehensive Bluetooth functionality, using Swift.  I'm currently stuck on how to send events back to React Native from Swift.  I attempted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870775/react-native-sending-events-to-javascript-in-swift) option, but `self.bridge` is always `nil`.  I'm hoping to build an interface file that will contain everything needed to bridge the functionality I need into Obj-C, and then JS (since I can't make the functions in the Bridge module listeners to `NSNotification` events or otherwise call them directly in Swift (I think).

**BTInterface.swift**

```
@objc(BTInterface)
class BTInterface: NSObject {
    var bridge: RCTBridge!

    @objc func shouldScanForPeripheral(shouldScan: Bool) {
        log.debug("Should scan: \(shouldScan)")
    }

    @objc func testEvent(eventName: String) {
        // self.bridge is always nil and crashes
        self.bridge.eventDispatcher.sendAppEventWithName( eventName, body: "Hello" )
    }
}
```

**BluetoothBridge.m**

```
#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"
#import "RCTEventDispatcher.h"

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(BTInterface, NSObject)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(shouldScanForPeripheral:(BOOL *)shouldScan);
RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(testEvent:(NSString *)eventName)

@end
```

then I would like to call this from my Bluetooth logic like so:

```
BTInterface().testEvent("TestEvent")
```

Exploring some [other](https://github.com/kirkness/react-native-swift-socketio/blob/master/RNSwiftSocketIO/Socket.swift#L22-L24) [modules](https://github.com/bh5-pods/react-native-gcm/blob/master/iOS/GCM.swift) that do similar things, I tried adding the following, to no avail:

**added to BTInterface.swift**

```
@objc func initWithBridge(_bridge: RCTBridge) {
    self.bridge = _bridge
}
```

Comment: this should help [React Native - How to bridge a Swift View](http://browniefed.com/blog/2015/11/28/react-native-how-to-bridge-a-swift-view/)

Comment: This addresses building a native View component, not setting up events.

Comment: did you figure it out @Chris?

Comment: Nope :-(.  I abandoned Swift because it was just so much extra overhead to making it work with the RN setup.